# Add values of input of same class javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do i add values of input of same class. I have tried the code below but doesn't seem to work. Where am i going wrong?

```
<table id="tableID">
<tr>

<td>   <input name="name" class="compulsory1" type="text" value="1" />  </td>
<td>   <input name="name1" class="compulsory1" type="text" value="2" />  </td>
<td>   <input name="name2" class="compulsory1" type="text" value="3" />  </td>

<td>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tdsCompulsory = document.getElementsByClassName('compulsory1')[0].value;
var cData = [];
sum = 0;
for(var i in tdsCompulsory){
    if(typeof tdsCompulsory[i].textContent != 'undefined')
    cData.push(tdsCompulsory[i].textContent);
}
console.log(cData);

for(var i in cData){
    sum +=parseInt(cData[i]);
}
alert (sum);
</script>

</td>

</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this , use `querySelectorAll` , You will get all elements in the document with class="compulsory1":

```js
window.onload = function(){
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".compulsory1");
var total = 0;
for(var i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{
total+=Number(x[i].value);
}
console.log(total);
}
```

```html
  <input name="name" class="compulsory1" type="text" value="1" /> 
  <input name="name1" class="compulsory1" type="text" value="2" /> 
  <input name="name2" class="compulsory1" type="text" value="3" />
```

Answer (score 2):

In your solution tdsCompulsory is not a array, it's just a number of first element(input).

```js
var tdsCompulsory = document.getElementsByClassName('compulsory1');
var len = tdsCompulsory.length;
var cData = [];
sum = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < len; i++){
    cData.push(tdsCompulsory[i].value);
    sum += +tdsCompulsory[i].value 
}
alert (sum);
```

```html
<table id="tableID">
<tr>

<td>   <input name="name" class="compulsory1" type="text" value="1" />  </td>
<td>   <input name="name1" class="compulsory1" type="text" value="2" />  </td>
<td>   <input name="name2" class="compulsory1" type="text" value="3" />  </td>

<td>
```

.

Answer (score 1):

Here

```
var tdsCompulsory = document.getElementsByClassName('compulsory1')[0].value;
```

your `tdsCompulsory` is a single element, because you get `[0]` element.

Change your code to

```
var tdsCompulsory = document.getElementsByClassName('compulsory1');

for(var i = 0; i < tdsCompulsory.length; i++){
    if(typeof tdsCompulsory[i].value != undefined){
       cData.push(tdsCompulsory[i].textContent);
    }
}

    console.log(cData);

for(var i in cData){
    sum +=parseInt(cData[i]);
}
alert (sum);
```

or use `foreach` method

```
[].foreach.apply(tdsCompulsory, (el) => {
   if(typeof tdsCompulsory[i].value != undefined){
        cData.push(tdsCompulsory[i].value);
     }
});
```

Comment: Does that capture the values?

Comment: When i use ur code like this. it doesnt alert total. could you help with a jsfiddle `<script type="text/javascript">
var tdsCompulsory = document.getElementsByClassName('compulsory1').value;
for(var i = 0; i < tdsCompulsory.length; i++){
    if(typeof tdsCompulsory[i].textContent != 'undefined')
    cData.push(tdsCompulsory[i].textContent);
}
console.log(cData);
sum = 0;
for(var j in cData){
    sum +=parseInt(cData[j]);
}
alert (sum);

</script>`

Answer (score 1):

You can write like below using jQuery:

```
   <table id="tableID">
                <tr>
                <td>   <input name="name" class="compulsory1" type="text" value="1" />  </td>
                <td>   <input name="name1" class="compulsory1" type="text" value="2" />  </td>
                <td>   <input name="name2" class="compulsory1" type="text" value="3" />  </td>
                <td>
        </table>
        <input type="Button" value="Show Sum" onclick="sumAll()">


     <script> 
        function sumAll(){
            var values = $('.compulsory1');
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i =0; i<values.length; i++) {
            console.log(values[i]);
            sum += parseInt($(values[i]).val());
        }
        alert(sum);
     }
    </script>
```

Thanks,
Ravi